# How can I make PHP zlib library output PNG compatible compression?

Tags: php, png, zlib

### Situation

I'm currently making a function that would create an image from user id. I've successfully generated raw RGBA pixels and also succesfully filtered them like this:

With image width being 22 px and height 2 px.

user id: `a308193d1eff2f15df7bedb4cb992bcf25cee012ca41751c35ce1d5500497063`, which will be padded if too short for generating pixels.

filtered raw pixels:

```
01a30819ff000000009a16e60000000000f2f7e000000000004cd8d5000000000050ac770000000000048ca3000000000011edfc00000000006163520000000000f45901000000000020322c00000000001b63b600000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I've also successfully generated a working SVG from user id but SVG is not what I'm after.

### Problem

PHP zlib library does not seem to correctly compress the data. It outputs always compressed data that is not compatible with PNG-format even though zlib is originally designed for PNG. Every zlib library funtion generates wrong compression like:

```
78da 635ccc21f99f010866893d03510c9fbe3f00d33e37ae82e98035e5609aa5673198167cfb074c27260781e92f918c605ac148074c4b276f03d34c0c340200 54f010d5
```

(I divided ZLIB header, compressed data and adler32 with space).

What it should output (or at least similar to):

```
0899 B5C1210A83500000D0E730582D03B1780093E730C8DAE2F0105EC213587F357B13C168B259646011B653F85E1492EC07C37303C7B9827A9941337620EE0348F70B7CDA17F8BE23505425C8DB093CDCE40F 54F010D5
```

**(For PNG, compressed string should always start with 0x08 byte)**

Only Adler32 checksum is correct every time.

I've tried every zlib compression function and every one of them generates useless data. Most configurable function of them are deflate_init() + deflate_add() but they are as useless as every other function.

For example:

```
$filtered_pixels = "01a30819ff000000009a16e60000000000f2f7e000000000004cd8d5000000000050ac770000000000048ca3000000000011edfc00000000006163520000000000f45901000000000020322c00000000001b63b600000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

$options = array(
    "level" => 9, // Best compression
    "memory" => 1, // No need to use much memory for such small image
    "window" => 8, // 256-bit window size
    "strategy" => ZLIB_RLE, // Especially good for PNG compression
    "dictionary" => "", // No dictionary
    );

$context = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE , $options);
$deflate = deflate_add($context, hex2bin($filtered_pixels));

// Outputs "1819 625ccc21f99f010866893d6300814fdf1f308080cf8dab0c2010b0a69c0104587a16338080e0db3f0c2090981cc400025f2219194040c148870104a493b731800013038d00000000ffff" without adler32 checksum
echo bin2hex($deflate);
```

I've struggled with this problem for a week now and it just won't work what ever function I try with what ever parameters I try per function. Am I missing something obvious? I am also aware how to encode PNG from other parts and I've done it. Only IDAT chunk compression is what causes me to lose my mind.

Comment: That is a very interesting topic, but I don't know anything about that. Reading http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Compression.html maybe `Note that the zlib compression method number is not the same as the PNG compression method number.` gives a useful hint.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not always start with a `0x08`. I have no idea where you're getting that from. Both `78da` and `0899` are valid zlib headers. There is nothing wrong whatsoever with the zlib stream that starts with `78da`. Both streams are valid, and both decompress to your data. Both can be used in the IDAT block of a PNG image.

Though I do have some quibbles with the one you seem to think "should" be the output. That one is rather poorly compressed, wasting space on a dynamic block header when it should have used a fixed header, and not compressing many runs of zeros. As a result, that deflate stream is 32% larger than the one generated by zlib. I wonder what made the poorly-compressed one.